# How to get WordPress post featured video url

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get WordPress post featured video url,
 When the post has a video format
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your question, read it yourself. Show us some related code, what video, what post, what format?

Comment: I want to get this link look please I put the picture

Comment: Where do you want to have it?